# jquery fade element does not show elements styled 'visibility: hidden'

Tags: jquery, visibility, fadein

I have a bunch of thumbnails which I am loading with a style of `visibility: hidden;` so that they all maintain their correct layouts. Once the page is fully loaded I have a jquery function that fades them in. This worked when their style was set to `display: none;` but obviously the layout screwed up then. Any suggestions?

Heres the fade line:

```
$('.littleme').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Add a few calls to the chain like this:

```
 $('.littleme').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

This will change it to `display:none` for 1 frame before fading in, occupying the area again.

Comment: Cheers works well. No noticeable delay or shift in that 1 frame.

Comment: and the reverse: `$('.littleme').fadeOut(speed,function(){$('.littleme').css("visibility","hidden").css("display","");});` :-)

Comment: @eruciform -  to eliminate the `display: none` at the end, you can just do `$('.littleme').fadeTo(speed, 0);`, which won't set `display` at the end, same effect with less work :)

Comment: `$('.littleme').fadeTo(speed, 0, function(){ $(this).hide();});` for setting it to `display:none` after the animation. thanks @NickCraver for the original snippet :)

Answer (score 28):

try using opacity and `animate()`:

```
$('.littleme').css('opacity',0).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
```

Comment: I am always a bit weary of using opacity in regards to css because of IE. Presumably jquery handles this with no problems???

Comment: This won't work since it's still not visible, test to see for yourself.

Comment: of course, you have to remove the visibility:hidden. And yes, jQuery handles the opacity issue in IE.

Comment: Edge case. If there is iframe content inside an opacity: 0 wrapper, jquery will not be able to animate this is for IE. You can use filter: inherit to try and help out with this issue, but if the iframe is out of your control (i.e. social sharing widgets) you may have to go with the excepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

`<span style="opacity:0;">I'm Hidden</span>`

To Show : `$('span').fadeTo(1000,1)`

To Hide  : `$('span').fadeTo(1000,0)`

The space is preserved in the DOM layout

http://jsfiddle.net/VZwq6/

Comment: Since opacity isn't supported in IE<9 and I want to start with an invisible state I coupled this solution with https://github.com/bladeSk/internet-explorer-opacity-polyfill

Comment: Thank you - great advice - worked for me in my case when the element that I have added - was blinking in for one millisecond before disappearing and starting to fadeIn. :) THe fadeTo and opacity:0 - resolved the issue of blinking of the element after I added it to the dom and before gave the command to fadeIn.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you use fadeTo(duration, value) instead? Surely this way you can fade to 0 and 1, that way you are not affecting the document flow...

Answer (score 0):

Try matching for the hidden element?

$(".littleme:hidden").fadeIn();