# Getting rid of a delay in fading in an item

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

If you see [this JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/L7ZFR), I'm simply trying to animate in a button/link, albeit in a certain way. I want the link to still apply in layout so that the layout doesn't change at all.

My HTML:

```
<p>
    <a id="helloWorld" href="#" class="btn primary large">Hello, World! &raquo;</a>
    Fork this to get hacking on <span class="label stark">Bootstrap</span> and <span class="label stark">jQuery</span>.
</p>
```

My CSS:

```
#helloWorld { 
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$("#helloWorld")
    .delay(1000) // after a second
    .css("visibility", "visible") // make it 'visible
    .hide() // but hide it 
    .fadeIn(500); // then fade it in
```

I have to do the `visibility:visible` then `hide()` hack [as noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden). The weird thing is that if I disable my JavaScript altogether, the link takes up the space normally. If I enable the JavaScript, then the layout gets all messed up. It appears that for some reason, it's executing the `css()` and the `hide()` *before* the delay is over! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because .delay() does not work the same as javascript's setTimeout. Check out http://api.jquery.com/delay/ for more documentation on that.

Try this fix:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#helloWorld").css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn(500);
}, 1000);
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7LGrS/2/

Comment: So is it pretty safe to say that `delay()` only works with other animations, but not with other jQuery operations? Is that why my code wasn't working?

Comment: Yes, the `.delay()` works on jQuery's `fx` queue. Other jQuery operations do not use the `fx` queue, so `delay()` is kinda useless there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style='display:none; ' id="helloWorld" href="#" class="btn primary large">
 Hello, World! &raquo;
</a>

just add the style to the anchor
```

Comment: But then it doesn't occupy any space in the layout?

Comment: Create a div of same size with explicit width and height. Then, in it, drop the anchor.

Comment: TK Kocheran, you want the button to just appear after 1 second, fading in, correct? If so, your code is correct because DELAY DOES WORK AS TIMEOUT. A second (1000 ms) is a second either in DELAY or SETTIMEOUT. The css("visibility","visible") and hide() are unecessary. If you just create a holding place for the button, it will work. I changed your fiddle and tested it before answering. But I do not have an account there or want to create one. I use my own domain for my examples (zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com).

Comment: I am assuming that your script is being ran from the document-ready. Counters of this kind would start only after the document is loaded, if put in there.

Comment: Sorry if I could not help. My intentions where the best.