# Jquery fadeIn() on a DIV with already set opacity style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV which is created dynamically in javascript code with the following style set:

```
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
-moz-opacity: 0;
-khtml-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
```

I want to fadeIn the DIV using Jquery, but it doesn't work. The DIV still has opacity:0. I can't use fadeOut on the div because it is created dynamically and I need to fadeIn immediately after the image in the DIV has been loaded.

Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset the CSS manually and then fade it in:

```
$("#myDiv").css({"-ms-filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=1)", "-moz-opacity": 1, "-khtml-opacity": 1, "opacity": 1, "visibility": hidden}).fadeOut(0, function(){

     $(this).css({"visibility": "visible"}).fadeIn();
})
```

I use this a lot for things I need to start out hidden and then fade in.

Comment: the problem is that the visibility: visible shows the content right away, and therefore I can't see the fadeIn taking place

Comment: fadeOus is also not good because the div is not created yet by javascript and it's now in the form yet

Comment: This ones works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden - is that what you've meant?

Comment: Lol that's a shorthand version of exactly what I wrote, look at the end of the first line, there's a fadeout(0), then the visibility: visible and fade in are in the callback :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `animate` instead.

```
$('#your_div_id').animate({opacity: 1});
```

Comment: I can't, the div is not created yet, and when it does it should be already at opacity 0 by default

Comment: use `animate` AFTER you've created the `div` to bring it into view, after the image loads. Unless I don't understand -- are you trying to show the div or hide it?

Comment: When the DIV is first inserted into the document it should be not visible. The DIV contains an image. After the DIV is inserted and the image has been loaded, this trigger a function that needs to fadeIn the DIV and the image inside it. display:none doesn't work because it ruin some size calculations and I won't use it. visibility: hidden seems good, but when I run fadeIn it doesn't work, Jquery doesn't fadeIn a DIV with visibility hidden.

Comment: Right, so start with `opacity: 0` and change the `opacity` once the image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the image with `display: none` instead of messing with the opacity, then fade it in.

Comment: display none is not good because I make some calculations that cannot be done on a div in a display:none state

Comment: I thought about using a javascript in onload of the div?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use liveQuery (jquery plugin): https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

"Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated."

```
$('.someClass').livequery(function() { 
    /*a .someClass is created*/
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

liveQuery works nice!