# Want to use jquery fade in effects, but want to use visibility:hidden initially

Tags: jquery

It seems most of the jquery fadein/out and animate functions are based on the initial element having display:none as opposed to visibility:hidden.

What if I want the initial element to take space up on the page (i.e. use visibility:hidden), but then use a fade in/out or slide effect? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: @StuartKershaw, that question has no relevance at all that I can see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery fade element does not show elements styled 'visibility: hidden'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden)

Answer (score 8):

Sure, start with `visibility: hidden` then do:

```
$('.your-element').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();
```

Borrowed from a [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2435815/949328) question.

Answer (score 8):

You may also try something like this ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dL4kt/1/)) as `fadeIn`

```
$('div').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
```