# jQuery fadein with find

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to get an element fade in with when making it visible, tried a few different combinations and it doesn't seem to be working as yet.

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
    $(this).find("a .hover-btn").css({
        visibility:     "visible"
    }).fadeIn(3000);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
$(this).find("a .hover-btn").fadeIn(3000);
```

`fadeIn` automatically makes the element visible.

Comment: That doesn't bring anything up, I've already got the visibility set to hidden in CSS, would that be having an effect?

Comment: I got working, your answer was correct Amit (thanks mate!), with a slight adjustment due to using visibility:hidden instead of display:none. FYI for anyone else in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817551/want-to-use-jquery-fade-in-effects-but-want-to-use-visibilityhidden-initially#answer-19817623