# Fade in using jQuery while holding position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

### What I have currently

I currently have some text that starts off as `display:none`, and I use jQuery to `fadeIn()` the text.   The issue I'm having is that because the text is centered, as each word fades in, the position of the words on the line keeps moving (they are centering as the paragraph grows).

I understand *why* this happens.   I'm using `display:none`.   So, what I am trying to do is use `invisibility:hidden` instead, so that all of the words keep their final position on the page.

### My issue moving forward

The problem I am running in to is that when I switch to `invisibility:hidden`, I can't seem to find a way to fade the content in.    I did use the suggestion made in this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden), but unfortunately that seems to give me the same effect as I have currently.

I'm hoping someone can help me understand how to fade in from hidden without moving elements around.

### My Code

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">    
<h1 id="cfs">Charles Samet</h1>
    <p class="intro">
        <span id="fade1">Husband.</span>
        <span id="fade2">  Father.</span>
        <span id="fade3">  Computer Geek.</span>
        <span id="fade4">  Welcome to my world...</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {text-align:center}
#fade1, #fade2, #fade3, #fade4 {display:none; font-size:125%;}
#cfs {display:none}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cfs').fadeIn(2500);
    $('#fade1').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#fade2').delay(5000).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#fade3').delay(7000).fadeIn(2000);
    $('#fade4').delay(9000).fadeIn(2000);           
});
```

And here is a CodePen demo of the current functionality:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xocyw/

And here is a CodePen of what I've tried, using invisibility:hidden, with no success:   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdlHJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to animate opacity. That way you'll avoid `display: none` and get the same results.

CSS

```
element {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(element).animate({opacity: 1});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/H6jts/

And btw. there is no rule `invisibility`, but `visibility`.

---

Here is the working version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/3js5e/

Comment: Excellent, thank you...  works exactly as I needed.   I will definitely keep this in my bag of tricks.   Again, many thanks.