# display a div after its contents is loaded

Tags: jquery, image, html, document-ready

I have a div on my website wich contains images, texts and links.
It's a carousel.

what I'm trying to do is to display the div after all the contents is loaded. I want to use opacity 0 siwtch to opacity 1, with a fade in effect.

here is my html :

```
<div id="slideshow">

    <div id="carousel">

        <li><a href="en/article-1/"><img width="657" height="394" src="wp-content/uploads/41.jpg" class="image_slideshow wp-post-image" alt="4" nopin="nopin" /></a><div class="legende">&nbsp;</div></li>

        <li><a href="en/article-3/"><img width="657" height="394" src="wp-content/uploads/21.jpg" class="image_slideshow wp-post-image" alt="2" nopin="nopin" /></a><div class="legende">&nbsp;</div></li>

        <li><a href="en/article-4/"><img width="657" height="394" src="wp-content/uploads/11.jpg" class="image_slideshow wp-post-image" alt="1" nopin="nopin" /></a><div class="legende">&nbsp;</div></li>

        <li><a href="en/article-5/"><img width="795" height="476" src="wp-content/uploads/6.jpg" class="image_slideshow wp-post-image" alt="6" nopin="nopin" /></a><div class="legende">&nbsp;</div></li>

    </div>

    <ul id="carousel-descriptions">

        <li class="desc">This is article 1</li>

        <li class="desc">This is article 3</li>

        <li class="desc">this is article 4</li>

        <li class="desc">this is article 5</li>

    </ul>

    <div id="carousel-controls">


        <span class="control"></span>


        <span class="control"></span>


        <span class="control"></span>


        <span class="control"></span>


    </div>

    <div class="prev_slide">

        <img src="../../../wp-content/uploads/structure/prev.jpg">

    </div>

    <div class="next_slide">

        <img src="../../../wp-content/uploads/structure/next.jpg">

    </div>

</div>
```

I tried something like this, but it's not working :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideshow').css('opacity','0');
        $('#slideshow').load(function() {
  $(this).css('opacity','1');  
    }); 
}
```

is there a way of doing it ? with fade in to display the div.
i can't use display none because my carousel need to be displayed to work

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

set its `visibility` to `hidden` in its style attribute in html markup, and then use this:

```
<div id="slideshow" style="visibility:hidden;">


$(window).load(function () {
  $('#slideshow').css('visibility','visible');
}
```

`$(window).load` waits until all images are loaded

or you could refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163865/3406576) guy's post, where he shares a plugin that allows waiting for a specific element's images to load

Comment: thanks @Banana, I know how to use the window.load function, but is it possible to replace $(window), by $(#slideshow) ? I don't want to wait until the whole window is loaded, but only the #slideshow... i don't know if it's posssible or if there's a way to do it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options here that give you the fade in while avoiding `display:none;`:

```
<div id="slideshow">...</div>
```

Using opacity:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slideshow').css('opacity',0).animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
});
```

Using visibility:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#slideshow').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

References: 
[jquery fade element does not show elements styled 'visibility: hidden'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden)