# In what order/priority does a browser get information from CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I basically had the same problem as the person in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435751/jquery-fade-element-does-not-show-elements-styled-visibility-hidden).

The suggested solution was:

```
$('.littleme').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

This piece of code feels really weird to me. I thought the browser builds the DOM using HTML/CSS and i can then freely manipulate it using JS/jQuery - why do i still have to change the CSS?

I am a CSS and Javascript beginner, so could someone please explain to me, why i have to manipulate the CSS before being able to use jQuery to fade in my element?

Comment: Are you asking why something has to be hidden before it can be faded in, and why jQuery doesn't consider visiblity hidden as being "hidden" ?

Comment: I had the same problem when i used `opacity: 0;` to initially hide my elements. I also had to set the opacity back to 1 manipulating the css before being able to fade it. I am not quite understanding how all of these play together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's `css()`, `hide()` and `fadeIn()` methods all change the DOM rather than the CSS you've loaded in.

In this case you change the visibility style first using `css()`, then `hide()` changes the display style to `none` and then `fadeIn()` changes the display style to `block` but does so by tweening the transparency.

Comment: This is what i needed to finally understand, what is going on, thank you! I guess my question is phrased rather badly, but it's hard to name the things you don't understand in the beginning of learning something new.

Answer (score 1):

The `.css()` jQuery method updates the DOM element's `style` object. It doesn't touch the actual CSS stuff that you imported via `<style>` elements on the page.

Element style overrides styles implied by CSS. Performing those changes via jQuery (or direct use of DOM APIs) is affecting the structures established by `style` properties mixed into the HTML markup:

```
<div class=foo style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
```

for example. The contents of that "style" attribute are parsed and used to construct the `style` property of the DOM node. That's what's affected by the jQuery `.css()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` plays with the `display` attribute.
But if the `visibility` is set to `hidden`, obviously no result can be seen.

That is why the answer you found talks about setting the `visibility` to `visible` first.

Comment: Can you please explain how hide and fadeIn manipulate the `display` attribute? I only know about `display: block` or `display: inline` in CSS.

Comment: @LucaFülbier `.hide()` sets `display` to `none`. `.fadeIn()` sets `display` to `block` and then gradually increases `opacity`. On the other hand, there is `visibility: hidden`, which is not taken into account in these functions.

Comment: It would be good for you to read jQuery docs instead: [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: You are totally right, i never would've thought, that it would change the display attribute while fading it in using opacity.